# can I use session cookie instead of csrf?

Tags: cookies, go, session-cookies, csrf, csrf-protection

I have been reading about csrf and fiddliN around with implementing it using go and gorilla toolkit. I am also using gorilla sessions which i have implemented to store a user id in an encrypted cookie.

the cookie is decrypted and i fetch the user from the db with the now unencrypted key-value store using a middleware I wrote...

if the user is creating the session cookie from authentication through an oauth2 provider, do i have any need to implement csrf protection if all the views that need such protection are only allowed to authed users anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose a user has logged into your site, and has continued to browse the Internet in the same session. They stumble across another site which is maliciously targeting yours, with HTML or JS that causes the user's browser to make a request to an endpoint on your site. This will contain the user's session cookie for your domain, and succeed unless protected by a CSRF token.